# UISearchBar Refuses to Change Width?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I am adding a UISearchBar to a UINavigation Bar as so (this is a storyboard based app) :

```
//Setup the search bar.
    searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 50.0f, 44.0f)];
    self.tabBarController.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar;
    searchBar.delegate = self;
    controller = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc]initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar contentsController:self];
    controller.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    controller.searchResultsDelegate = self;
```

No matter what I set the width and height and position of the search bar to be, it will not change the height / width of the search bar. It is always the same width and height.

Can anyone suggest how to alter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've experienced the same problem one time, and what I did was adding the searchBar into a container View (i've had problems showing the cancel button) and add the container view as a left bar item

```
 - (UIBarButtonItem *)createSearchBarHolder {
       UIView *searchBarContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:navigationSearchBar.frame];
       searchBarContainer.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
      [searchBarContainer addSubview:navigationSearchBar];
      navigationSearchBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
      UIBarButtonItem *searchBarHolder = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:searchBarContainer];
      return searchBarHolder;
  }
```

And in viewDidLoad:

```
     NSArray *leftBarButtons = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[self createSearchBarHolder], nil];
     self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = leftBarButtons;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what size you want your search bar to be. If you make it the navigation item's titleView, it will adjust for any buttons on the navigation bar, and adjust on rotation. Is that what you want?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UISearchBar *sb = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = sb;
}
```